# AndroidAlarmManagerPlus not starting automatically after reboot

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-packages

I've set permissions in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

I've also added the following lines in the AndroidManifest.xml as specified in the docs

```
<service
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmService"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.AlarmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:exported="false"/>
<receiver
    android:name="dev.fluttercommunity.plus.androidalarmmanager.RebootBroadcastReceiver"
    android:enabled="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In my main.dart file, I've the following lines of codes...

```
import 'package:android_alarm_manager_plus/android_alarm_manager_plus.dart';
```

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();
  runApp(MyApp());
  await AndroidAlarmManager.periodic(Duration(minutes: 1), 0, syncData);
}
```

```
void syncData() async {
  print("synching data");
  String? uploadedUrl = await S3.uploadToS3();
  print(uploadedUrl);
}
```

What should I add for this to work automatically on reboot? TIA :)

Answer (score 0):

From Android 8.0 You can't use most of the implicit broadcast ,
So your application service will not start on
**ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED** or **ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED**

[for more details](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions)

you can use **WorkManager** instead to sync data to server
[here is a good example](https://medium.com/swlh/periodic-tasks-with-android-workmanager-c901dd9ba7bc)